# Chromecast Custom Receiver player stuck on an IDLE state and doesn't respond

Tags: javascript, chromecast, google-cast

I am trying to fix the issue when a sender (android app) send a queue of audio items. Few of those items can be with an invalid URL
When it happens the receiver occurs an error and set the player to an IDLE state.
Then I try to click on play next button or do something else on my android app - the receiver doesn't respond.
What am I doing wrong?

[screenshot of the chrome console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cl7B0.png)
[screenshot of the chrome console 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQVCY.png)

Comment: I use this [player](https://github.com/googlecast/CastReferencePlayer) as a reference

Comment: Are you using the CAF receiver?

Comment: I'm using the Develop Receiver v2 App. I've tried the CAF receiver, but it didn't resolve my problem

Answer (score 0):

You may try these suggestions discussed in [Media events](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/custom_receiver#events):

> Receiver applications can tweak this logic by applying their own heuristics and changing the state in the [`customizedStatusCallback`](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/receiver/cast.receiver.MediaManager#customizedStatusCallback) API. This API will provide the current state, and the application can return a modified state.
>
> The receiver app can also not to go to IDLE after `ended` or `error` by overriding [`onEnded`](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/receiver/cast.receiver.MediaManager#onEnded) / [`onError`](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/receiver/cast.receiver.MediaManager#onError), if this makes sense in a particular scenario.

Comment: I've tried to set different states when error occurs, but it didn't help me.
The problem that receiver doesn't accept any new load requests